# Refresh list after server callback in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I fetch a collection from the server and I would like to get detail for each item. All requests are received correctly, but the paragraph Loading... doesn't hide.

```
<h2 ng-repeat-start="server in hypervisors track by server.ip | orderBy:server.ip">
    {{server.ip}}
</h2>
<div ng-repeat-end>
    <p ng-hide="{{server.loaded}}" class="ng-hide">Loading...</p>
```

When I uncomment the line in controller before post everything works fine.

```
vmwareStatusApp.controller('Home', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.post('Home/ListHypervisors').success(function (data) {
        $scope.hypervisors = data;
        $scope.listLoaded = true;

        $scope.hypervisors.forEach(function (item) {
            //item.loaded = true; // this line works
            $http.post('Home/HostInfo', { 'ip': item.ip }).success(function (data) {
                $scope.hypervisors[0].loaded = true;
                    item.loaded = true;
                    item.detail = data;
                })
                .error(function(data) {
                    item.loaded = true;
                    item.error = data;
                    item.displayError = true;
                });
        });
    });
});
```

There are many posts about refreshing view, but I haven't found any working for me. Neither anti-patter with calling `$digest()` didn't work, because of multiple callback. Which part of AngularJS tutorial have I skipped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the braces from your `ng-hide` like this

```
ng-hide="server.loaded"
```

ng-hide and angular directives should be read like this :

```
ng-directive = "somethingAngularWillInterpret"
```

The opposite exemple is in your HTML angular will not know what he should interpret instead of just showing some text

```
<b>server.loaded</b> will show a bold "server.loaded"
```

To notice angular that he need to interpret we will use the braces

```
<b>{{somethingAngularWillInterpret}}</b> will show a bold result of the interpretation
```

EDIT :

<s>So doing this ng-hide="{{server.loaded}}" is probably saying to angular to interpret the result of the server.loaded interpretation like a var named true or a var named false (just speculation, i need to try it).</s>

Just tested it, this just lead to a syntax error.

Comment: @JanZahradník I edited and added some more information. If this solve your problem, don't forget to mark this as a valid answer. And btw, don't look at $digest or $apply. You don't need it in 99% of angular use cases and could lead to performances issues

Comment: Many thanks for explanation, now the difference is clear for me. Btw. how can you check the syntax of Angular? It can prevent such questions, but Chrome doesn't complained.

Comment: @JanZahradník the chrome javascript console just gave me an error when i tried this syntax.  The expression was invalid starting by {